# Is it possible to get case-sensitive filename handling in Cygwin 64-bit running on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, ntfs, cygwin

I have been using Cygwin 32-bit on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. I had the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\ObCaseInsensitive` registry key set and all has been good: I could get true case-sensitive filename handling, I could create `FOO.txt` and `foo.txt` in the same directory.

Now that Cygwin 64-bit is released, I want to try it on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. It turns out that the ObCaseInsensitive registry key has no effect for Cygwin 64-bit because the key seems to be for the Win32 subsystem only. Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications (SUA) is also not available in Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (Enterprise or Ultimate is required). In fact, I don't even know if having SUA installed would help at all.

Does anybody know if it is possible to get case-sensitive filename handling with Cygwin 64-bit on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case sensitivity does work on x86_64-cygwin.  Remember that on 64-bit Windows systems, there are effectively two registries, one for 32-bit processes and another for 64-bit processes.  (In Cygwin, these are represented by `/proc/registry32` and `/proc/registry64`.)  Setting the key again with `regtool -w` and rebooting should fix this for you.

Comment: Mea culpa. Further tests confirm that the `ObCaseInsensitive` key *does* have an effect on Cygwin 64-bit: I could `echo 'FOO' > FOO.txt; echo 'bar' > foo.txt` and create two different files. The problem seems to be with `git`. `git` in Cygwin 64-bit doesn't seem to be patched to have correct case-sensitive filename handling, despite the `ObCaseInsensitive` registry key having been set.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function that checks the case of the target directory (without having to change the Windows Registry). This way, I have in `~/.bash_functions` file the following code:

```
unset cd_func2 2> /dev/null
unalias cd 2> /dev/null
cd_func2 () {

    echo $1 | grep -q '^/' && cd $1 && return 0
    for f in `echo $1 | sed -e 's/\// /g'` ; do
        _NEW_PATH=$(ls -a | grep -i ^"$f"$)
        [ "$_NEW_PATH" ] && cd $_NEW_PATH && continue
        echo "Directori inexistent $f" && return 1
    done
}

alias cd=cd_func2
```

EDIT: More general parameter handling.

Hope it helps.